# How do I query helper properties

Tags: entity-framework

For a little bit of background, I have to make some changes to the DB schema that I'm working on, and I want to avoid changing all of my queries.

I was hoping that I could do this by using helper properties.

---

Suppose I have the following model

```
public class Table1
{
    [Key]
    public int Table1Id { get; set; }

    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }

    public int TotalValue {get; set;}
}
```

and I have a lot of queries like this

```
var TotalValues = db.Table1s
    .Select(t => new Table1ViewModel
    {
        Foo = t.TotalValue
    })
    .ToList();
```

I want to be able to remove `TotalValue` and calculate it on the fly without searching my app for every place that uses `TotalValue`.

---

What I'm hoping to be able to do is just change `Table1` to the following

```
public class Table1
{
    [Key]
    public int Table1Id { get; set; }

    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int TotalValue 
    {
        get { return Value1 + Value2; }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I do that, I get a `NotSupportedException` when I run the query.

> 'TotalValue' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do? or at least something like it?

Comment: Not really.  You cannot use anything that is not mapped to the database in an EF query.  Also, EF and Linq to Sql are completely different technologies.  One of the tags is probably not applicable to what you are doing